# JavaScript: Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

i start to programm a chat but i became always this error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined**

But I defined **const username = user.displayName;**

this is a part of my code:

```
function authStateListener() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      const username = user.displayName;
    } else {
      window.location.href = "../pages/login.html";
    }
  });
};
```

and there is the error:

```
fetchChat.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
  const messages = snapshot.val();

  const now = (new Date().toLocaleDateString()).split(".");
  const t = (messages.date).split(".");

  if( t[0] < now[0]) {
      const message = `<li class=${username === messages.username ? "sent" : "receive"}><span class="name">${messages.username} </span><br>${messages.message}<br><span class="time">${t[0] - now[0]} Days ago</span></li>`;
      addMsg(message);
  } else {
      const message = `<li class=${username === messages.username ? "sent" : "receive"}><span class="name">${messages.username} </span><br>${messages.message}<br><span class="time">${messages.time}</span></li>`;
      addMsg(message);
  }
  //const message = `<li class=${username === messages.username ? "sent" : "receive"}></span>${messages.message}</li>`;
});
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: `const` is block scope. So `username` is only available in side the `if`, not outside it. But you don't even use it here. Even if this was a `var` it's still only going to be scoped to the function.

Comment: authStateListener is not returning anything

Comment: @Nonik like this **`return username = user.displayName;`** ?

Comment: @Leonvit return should be in the next line for code readability. Also please learn difference between const, let and var.  Using const in this case is not a good idea